# Check if matrix contains valid elements

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, indices, error-checking

I have this array

```
scale=np.array([-3,0,2,4,7,10,12])
```

And this matrix

```
matrix=np.array([[17, 10, 10],
       [10, 12, 12],
       [ 7,  7,  4],
       [-3, 11,  2]])
```

Now i want to know the indices of the rows in matrix which doesn't contain any of the elements in scale. The output should be:

```
array([0,3])
```

I've tried with np.where, np.all and np.any without solving the problem.

Do you have a simple solution to this?

Comment: maybe the output should be `array([0,3])`?

Comment: I am confused.  You say you want the row that doesn't contain any of the scale values, but each row and column of your matrix has at least one of the scale values.  And, to make matters more confusing, your answer lists the only 2 scale values not in the matrix.  Can you clarify what, exactly, you are looking for, please?  Are you looking for the scale values that are not present in the matrix?

Comment: I think you mean you want the indices of the rows that don't consist *entirely* of the scale values, i.e. at least one value in the row is not in `scale`.

Comment: Correct, its updated now, thanks @AlexanderYau

Comment: Im looking to find the indices of rows in which theres an invalid element (an invalid element is a value which is NOT a value in scale). @dkhamrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are rather looking for:

```
np.where(~np.in1d(matrix, scale).reshape(matrix.shape).all(axis=1))
#(array([0, 3], dtype=int64),)
```

Comment: Thanks. The output is a tuple, but in case of its an empty tuple, which it says to be (array([ ], dtype=int64),) how can i print "Empty tuple"?